# Calculate travel time between two latitude and longitude in angular google maps

Tags: angular, angular7

I have implement the angular google maps in my project. I am using `<agm-direction>` to display the directions. Now I want to calculate the travel time by bike between two latitudes and longitudes. I have browsed the internet but didn't get my solution.

```
<agm-map id="map" [latitude]='origin.lat' [longitude]='origin.lng' (mapReady)="addMarker()" [zoom]='15'>
    <agm-direction [origin]="origin" [destination]="destination" [renderOptions]="renderOptions" [markerOptions]="markerOptions">
    </agm-direction>
</agm-map>
```

```
public origin: {lat: 30.7224576, lng: 76.6984192};
public destination: {lat: 30.6949406, lng: 76.72605039999996};
 public renderOptions = {
        suppressMarkers: true,
    }

    public markerOptions = {
        origin: {
            icon: 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png',
            draggable: true,
        },
        destination: {
            icon: 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/red-dot.png',
            label: '',
            opacity: 0.8,
        },
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't it depend on the road options between two points? So, I think you need an API for getting road information.

Comment: I have the google maps api key and I am also displaying the map and direction through it but I do not know how can I calculate the travel time

Comment: Do you know what should the average speed of bike?

Answer (score 0):

First do you have the speed information or do you know average speed of bike.
Step 1 - First get the distance using below logic

```
function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {
  var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
  var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1);  // deg2rad below
  var dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1); 
  var a = 
    Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * 
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2)
    ; 
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
  var d = R * c; // Distance in km
  return d;
}

function deg2rad(deg) {
  return deg * (Math.PI/180)
}
```

Step 2 - formula of `time  = distance/speed`

Or you can check if google map provides any such method to get all these values based on traffic they can give the average speed.